# Isabelle syntax: operator not of function type

Tags: types, typeerror, isabelle

I am just starting using sets in Isabelle and have I have the following:

```
theory telephone
imports 
Main 
begin 

typedecl NAME
typedecl TELEPHONE

record TelephoneBook = 
KNOWN :: " NAME set"
NUMBER :: "(NAME * TELEPHONE) set"

locale telephone_book = 
fixes known :: " NAME set"
and number :: "(NAME * TELEPHONE) set"
assumes "known = Domain number"
begin

definition FindBirthday :: 
 "TelephoneBook => TelephoneBook => NAME => TELEPHONE => bool"
where 
"FindTelephone telephonebook telephonebook' name telephone == (
(name \<in> known)
∧ 
(telephone = number name)
)"
```

The problem lies with the line `telephone = number name` 
where i have the error message

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types " _ => _" and "_ set"

Type error in application: operator not of function type

Operator:  number :: (NAME × TELEPHONE) set
Operand:   name :: NAME
```

I've tried added parenthesis `(telephone = number (name))` or tilda `(telephone = number~name)` but it still has the same problem.

I know that number wants a NAME and TELEPHONE but i want to show that definition is correct when the output `telephone` should be the `telephone` when `name` is its domain.

Comment: Where does `date` come from?

Comment: sorry, i copied it down wrong. It should be `telephone` not date but i still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly what Isabelle says, i.e. that you can't use a set as a function, so you can't apply an argument to a set, in your case you can't apply `name` to `number`. What you may want is

`(name, telephone) : number`

or

`(name, telephone) ∈ number`.